# how to create a list of homogenous objects from JSON in Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have an array, that is a simple: `[ [String: AnyObject] ]`. This is just a regular JSON object. All objects in the array are the same type of object. My dictionary looks like this:

`[ { "firstName" : "Joe", "lastName": "Smith"}, {"firstName": "John", "lastName" : "Jones"} ]`

My Realm object is defined like this:

`public class Person : Object {
    public dynamic var firstName = ""
    public dynamic var lastName = ""
}`

I want to turn this JSON, into an object of type `List<Person>`

Ideally, I want to do something like this:

`let personList: List<Person> = unknown(arrayOfPersonDictionaries)`

I realize that I can just build a loop that will loop through each object in `arrayOfPersonDictionaries`, and create a Realm object on each one. I wast just wondering if there was a more convenient way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You describe that you want to have a `List<Person>` as return type. This type is used to manage relationships in Realm Swift.
So if you have another object class e.g. `House` with a relation `residents`, then you could simply create an object with all the persons from your array of dictionaries related to it with the following:

```
class House : Object {
     let residents = List<Person>()
}

try! realm.write {
   let people = [ { "firstName" : "Joe", "lastName": "Smith"}, {"firstName": "John", "lastName" : "Jones"} ]
   let house = realm.create(House.self, value: [ "residents": people ])
}
```

If you just want to get a suitable collection for a list of persisted objects, you can achieve that in a similar way:

```
try! realm.write {
   let arrayOfPersonDictionaries = [ { "firstName" : "Joe", "lastName": "Smith"}, {"firstName": "John", "lastName" : "Jones"} ]
   let people = arrayOfPersonDictionaries.map { realm.create(Person.self, value: $0) }
}
```

This will return an `Array<Person>`.

Comment: Sorry, I specified that it needs to be a List. It really doesn't. I was just trying to avoid making it an Array. So, I was just trying to use a more "realm-friendly" type of container, instead of a regular array.

Comment: No worries. There is a general semantic difference between the Realm collection types vs. the stdlib's collections though you shouldn't miss: Realm's collection are lazy and don't keep the objects in memory.

Comment: Right, that's why I was trying to avoid using an Array.

Comment: Then you could query for all objects after adding them to the Realm, there is no shortcut for that. I doubt though that this will bring any advantage as you had all the objects before in memory.

Comment: thanks for your help. Yeah, now that I think of it, what I'm asking for isn't really all that useful. The objects are already in memory, and they won't be around for long, in my case.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created an class which contains `List<Person>` then you only need to store a single Realm object, containing the full list.

To populate the list, you're going to have to iterate through the `arrayOfPersonDictionaries` to populate `personList`, but only one database save will be required